How to Efficiently Handle and Merge Large Datasets in Python Beyond Pandas' Capabilities?
I’m working on a data analysis project where I need to merge two large datasets, each with over 10 million rows, based on multiple columns. Initially, I considered using Pandas, but I’ve realized that it may not be the best tool due to performance issues with datasets of this size.
Here’s a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3],
    'Value1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Amount': [100, 200, 300]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 4],
    'Value2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    'Amount': [10, 20, 40]
})

I need to merge these datasets on the 'ID' column, but I also have a custom requirement to perform an operation on the 'Amount' columns from both datasets (e.g., multiplication) during the merge.
Given that Pandas struggles with very large datasets, what are the best alternatives in Python for efficiently handling this task?
I'm open to using libraries like dask, pyarrow, or even something like SQLAlchemy for this process. Performance is critical.

polars is a good alternative for large data sets

This question is similar to: Best way to join two large datasets in Pandas. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Listed Alternatives

I'm not a dask expert but in simple terms, it just tries to make pandas parallel. If you're trying to do joins with memory constraints then I don't think parallelism helps

pyarrow is a great way to store data and they even have good compiled functions in pyarrow.compute but it does joins in python so it won't be very performant

SQLAlchemy isn't going to help you on a stand alone basis. It's a means of creating SQL queries with a consistent API rather than writing them from scratch.


Unlisted Alternatives

polars is a newish DataFrame library written in rust with bindings to python that is built on arrow memory for exceptional zero-copy interoperability and speed. It is a very good choice

duckdb is basically a DB in memory. It lets you perform SQL queries against objects in python such as pyarrow tables, pandas DFs, polars DFs, and files. If you like SQL syntax then it might be worth trying before polars.

Using a database like postgres or mysql (I'm personally biased towards picking postgres) for millions of rows might be the right approach. If you go this route then you may want SQLAlchemy to interact with the database.


Decision
duckdb primarily uses sql queries whereas polars has an object oriented API. That said, polars does have a SQL based API but it isn't as feature complete as its own API. Similarly duckdb has an object based API but it isn't feature complete with the SQL interface. I would say to pick between them based on that until you hit an obstacle that the other specifically does better. They're both capable of reading csv, parquet, and other formats from the cloud. They both have much better performance than pandas. They can both handle (to some extent) out of memory jobs.
